# does the income-output-expenditure method of getting real gdp hold in ad as model

Tags: macroeconomics, supply-and-demand, keynesian-economics, aggregate-demand, aggregate-supply

in the ad as model, it seems there's two different real gdp for a given price level when in disequilibrium. does this mean the real gdp counted from the demand side is not equal to the real gdp counted from the supply side? if so then can we say, the income,expenditure and value added method of calculating gdp differs in this specific scenario?